# "be able to" in the past and future

Tags: modal-verbs

What does "*be able to*" imply when used in the future and past? When used in *the future* does it say that I will just have the ability to do it, and *maybe I'll do* it but *maybe not*? And when used in the past, does it say that I both *had the bility* and actually **did it**?

The future:

> He will be able to lift the car.
>
> I will be able to find Larry tomorrow.
>
> I will be able to come to the party.

The past: (was it done?)

> He was able to lift the car (off the child's leg).
>
> I was able to find Larry yesterday.
>
> I was able to come to the party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past tense, "He was able to..." strongly implies that he did whatever action you describe. The main exception to this is that if the speaker *explicitly* indicates that the action was not completed, that is understandable to mean simply that he had the ability. For example, "He was able to call home, but chose not to do so," means that he had the ability to call home, but he did not.

In the future tense, to *be able to* do something means that someone will have the ability to do something, but not necessarily that he will do it. We can't predict the future :)

Comment: I think there is an equally strong implication in the future case that the subject *intends* to perform the action when it becomes possible.

Comment: @Hellion I don't quite think so. Perhaps the implication is there, but I do not think it is equally strong.  For example, "Consumers will be able to purchase the toy for 75% off on black Friday."

Comment: A fair point.  Perhaps I can qualify it down to "when used in a first-person construction (as in the second and third example sentences), there is a strong implication of intent".

Comment: @Hellion I agree that there is some implication of intent, but I don't think it is as strong as in the past tense. To me, "I will be able to find Larry tomorrow" sounds like I could if I want to. "I was able to find Larry yesterday" sounds like I found him.

Comment: Outside of specific contexts, I don't think future tense ***will** be able to* has any special implications for whether you ***actually*** will, as opposed to *will have the **potential** to [do something]*. It's just that for the far more common past tense context, we have the commonplace alternative ***would have been** able to* to indicate that in principle we could, but actually we didn't. There's no natural short unambiguous phrasing for the same situation in the future (apart from anything else, what would it really *mean*?)

Answer (score -2):

He will be able to study in New Yors Univerity./.

Comment: It's not clear how this directly answers the examples in the question, and there's no explanation either. Can you [edit] to fix that?